# How to make a turn-based multi-player app on android and ios

Tags: android, ios, server, multiplayer

I want to make a simple turn based 2 player game for an android and IOS. I want the android users to be able to play with the IOS user as well. However I am unsure what I should use. It is similar to tick-tack-toe so only numbers will need to be exchanged from user to user. Can someone please point me into the right direction as to what server or client I should use. And if you could show me a tutorial series that shows me how to use it that would be great! I've googled everywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this service from google which support iOS and Android:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer